# cells off the screen in tableView are returning nil when accessed, swift

Tags: swift, hide, tableview, null

I'm trying to hide the cells in section 1 when I press a button.

When I have only a couple rows and all the rows in section 1 are visible my code works fine but when section 1 has more rows and some of them are off the screen(you have to scroll down to see them) my code crashes with unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

```
    func Action(sender: UIButton){

    var i = 0;
    var numberOFRows = Int(self.tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(1))

    for item in cellItemArray{
        if i < numberOFRows{

            let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: i++, inSection: 1)) as TableViewCell  // crashes here

            cell.layer.hidden = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you make all Cells hidden maybe you can create a new value

```
var control = 1
```

and then if you pressed button to hidden all Cells , change control value from 0 to 1 and

```
@IBAction func Button(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    control = 1
}
```

and you control this using Control statement if,"cellForRowAtIndexPath" method here,

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(cellItemArray[indexPath.row])"
    // Configure the cell...
    if control == 1{

        cell.layer.hidden = true

    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: that's perfect! Thanks for editing your answer and making it even more clear!! Hopefully it will help someone else!.